# Injecting multiple methods from onAction in fxml file to the controller directly using Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, controller, fxml, shortcut

I'm using Intellij IDEA, and i have fxml file that has multiple methods defined for an existing controller.

.fxml file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="188.0" prefWidth="164.0" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controllers.list.ExpensesList">
    <children>
        <Label style="-fx-font-family: arial; -fx-font-size: 20;" text="المصروفات" />
        <Hyperlink onAction="#showExpenses" style="-fx-font-family: arial; -fx-font-size: 17;" text="عرض المصروفات" />
        <Hyperlink onAction="#showAddExpense" style="-fx-font-family: arial; -fx-font-size: 17;" text="إدخال مصروف" />
        <Hyperlink onAction="#showRepeatedExpenses" style="-fx-font-family: arial; -fx-font-size: 17;" text="المصروفات المتكررة" />
        <Hyperlink onAction="#showExpenseCateogries" style="-fx-font-family: arial; -fx-font-size: 17;" text="تصنيفات المصروفات" />
    </children>
</VBox>
```

the methods are not defined in the controller yet. so my question is: how can I inject them all in the controller by one specific shortcut??
thanks.

Comment: For each unique `onAction` in the `FXML`, there needs to be a corresponding method in the `Controller`.

Comment: IDE does not know what controller class you are using in project. Specify the class in fxml file as `fx:controller="sample.Controller"` then use [Intention action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html) on method usages to create them in this class.